# Using complex type-constraints with generic functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics

Starting to use generic functions in Swift I have the following case:

```
func fillUpData<T:Class_One>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}

func fillUpData<T:Class_Two>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}
```

The two functions contain exactly the same internal code.

I want to make it one function, accepting both type Class_One and Class_Two for the second parameter.
In other words something like:

```
func fillUpData<T:Class_One|Class_Two>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}
```

Looking at the documentation, it seems I should be using “where clauses”, but I don’t know what would be the right syntax and what I tried did not really work.

For example, these did not work:

```
func fillUpData<T:Class_One,T:Class_Two>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}

func fillUpData<T where T:Class_One,T:Class_Two>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}

func fillUpData<T where T:Class_One|T:Class_Two>(bCard:Class_Data,dataForm:T) {
Some complex-Code …..
}
```

So, please let me know if you know the answer.

Comment: I believe you need to create a protocol which both classes implement, then make `T` conform to that protocol. Swift's standard library does this in the `findIndex<T: Equatable>` example in the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID186

Comment: I see. This seems very artificial though. Because I have no real need for a protocol here. And there should be a way to simply specify that T has to be a subclass of ClassOne or  a subclass of ClassTwo.

Comment: The problem is that unless the two classes inherit from a common class or protocol, there is no way to guarantee that both classes implement the methods or properties that your function requires them to have.  The protocol is used to bind the two classes together in a way that still keeps them independent from each other, but allows other functions to treat them as equal in a limited way. (I'm assuming that they do not have a common superclass in your case).

Comment: No, they do not have a common superclass, but in this particular case I think a common superclass would be more appropriate than a protocol.
Anyway I see your point, though I think there should be no problem to check that the two classes  implement the methods or properties that my function requires, in the same way it can be checked for one class.